# Save/Retrieve/Compare CheckboxList values from DB

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, checkboxlist

I am not sure if what i want is possible, but so far i have had no luck...

I am using Visual Studio, asp.net and SQL. a field in table in varchar(max) type...

What I want to do is save the values of CheckBoxList into the database and retrieve them to compare them in a SQL command to filter a few values from the table in database.

It's easier to understand when I give an example:

So I have these in HTML side of the code.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Sales</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Administration</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">Help</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

This in code to save the data

```
protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        TextBox20.Text = "";
        string s = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected)
                s += CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Value + ",";

            TextBox20.Text = s;
        }
    }
```

Now when some one chooses like two options, example `Sales` and `Administration`, I want the values 1,2 to be stored in the database in a single column.

**Then retrieve the values, using SQL show rows which have Sales or Administration / Sales and Administration in the column I want.**

I am not sure whether I am going about this the right way.. But any help would be appreciated.... I read that creating a table with all the values i need is they correct way.. but i dunno how it works..

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Thats what i did, dunno what went wrong.. Things were so messed up... Thankyou for correcting it..

Comment: Tip: Storing multiple values in a single column ("1,2") is generally a bad idea. It greatly complicates queries later, e.g. find all administrators who are engineers and not in sales. Using a separate table, e.g. `UserRoles`, and joining it with the `User` data is a common approach.

Comment: Sorry i still dont get the end part... I made a table, User and a table Interests... User table has UID and Interest table has IID.. Means i need to join the tables using these 2 ID's? and then when a user registers how do i know which user has which interests? If i made a separate table i dont get how 1 user selects more options

Comment: Check [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cfe57/1) for an example of how to do some queries. How would you do them with a list of numbers in one column? Would you assume the numbers in a column are sorted? How about adding or removing one role for one user?

Comment: Thats really helpful.. Im getting the concept a little bit... So how do i integrate it into my asp.net website using c#/loop/checkbox? and seeing your fiddile.. does this mean i need to use "Role1" and "Roll2" to retrive data? Do i have to write all combinations? Cant it be automatic, like if i ticked Roll1, Roll2 then few rows is displayed.. But if another user ticked Roll2,Roll3 then different rows is displayed..

Comment: That's way too broad a question to answer on SO. Part of it is trying a different database design and figuring out how to do the things you need to accomplish. Then you need to be able to do them from C#, e.g. you might want an `isAdmin( userId )` function. Finally it needs to be integrated into your website. Start working on it a step at a time and, if you need help, post specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would recommend the use of the StringBuilder class for doing string concatenation inside a loop as it is much more efficient -

> For routines that perform extensive string manipulation (such as apps that modify a string numerous times in a loop), modifying a string repeatedly can exact a significant performance penalty. The alternative is to use StringBuilder, which is a mutable string class.

[MSDN StringBuilder Class Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I agree with the comment above made by HABO, storing comma seperated values in a single column is almost always a bad idea. You should probably create a class called User. Give the User class properties such as 'name' and 'roles'.

With regards to the database structure for this data, once again I agree with HABO, two tables would be recommended. User and UserRoles. In the User table you would store data such as Id, Username, Age, etc. you can then in the UserRoles table store UserId (the Id from the User table), in this way a User can be assigned multiple roles.

If you want more detail feel free to ask and I'll try and provide example schema etc.

Comment: I feel i was doing this completely the wrong way... Im getting the concept now... It would be really helpful if anyone can post an example of using this with checkboxlist/database in asp.net..

Comment: Could you give a little more information on how you are interacting with the DB? (for example are you using Entity Framework?)

Comment: Sorry for my dumbness, not sure what it is... Im using the built in SQL Database system in Visual Studio 2010, i think it is called SQL Express

Comment: In order to interact with the database in SQL Express there are a few options available. I would recommend Entity Framework for what you are doing as it will easily map database objects (i.e. rows and columns) to C# objects which you can use in your code. Hopefully this will be useful - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/ee712907#getstarted